# express.static does not deliver

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, static, dirname

I searched through all topics, but could not find a similar issue.

I have a `server.js` in the folder `/build`

```
// /build/server.js

import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'static'), { maxAge: '30d' }));
```

and a css file in `/build/static/css/my.css`.
I start nodemon with `build/server.js` from the root folder `/`

I assume that I should get my file via localhost:8080/static/css/my.css
But it returns a 404 and "Cannot GET /static/css/my.css"

What could be the issue?
I tried a lot of different paths, but never got a successful response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `__dirname ` corresponds to `CWD` of the file. So, `path.join(__dirname,  'static`)` should solve the problem.

Comment: Was struggeling for a long time.
Now I dismissed the `__dirname` and it works. Is this good practice?

`app.use('/static', express.static(path.join('build/static'), { maxAge: '30d' }));`

The joined path was `/build/static` before and now is `build/static`.

Comment: yeah. looks good.

Comment: Thank you @MukeshSharma But this is still strange..... `console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'static'), path.join('build', 'static'), path.join('build/static'));` this gives me `/static build/static build/static`. I think the preceeding `/` is the problem.....I don’t quite understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to go with `__dirname` to prevent errors caused by relative paths to the directory the server is started from.

The main problem was that `__dirname` always returned `/`.
I added the following lines to my webpack config:

```
target: 'node', // was already there
node: { // has been added
  __filename: false,
  __dirname: false
},
```

You can find a closer description of this behaviour of __dirname in webpack here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2010#issuecomment-181256611